# How can I instantiate WPF elements via their type when they have StaticResources?

Tags: wpf, reflection, instantiation, staticresource

I need to instantiate WPF types (say, a UserControl or a Page) via reflection for a designer.  The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to instantiate these using Activator.CreateInstance I get a *TargetInvocationException* which wraps, in the end, an exception thrown by the **StaticResource** markup extension.

**Clarification:  The types are in a different assembly that is loaded at runtime!**

Apparently, **Activator.CreateInstance** can't instantiate types that use the **{StaticResource XXX}** markup extension, *even when the static resource is defined in the type's definition.*

So, if all you have is the following type's definition (Type + xaml file):

```
<Page x:Class="Hurr.Durr">
  <Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="whatever">
      <TextBlock Text="This is a stupid example."/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>
  <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource whatever}" />
</Page>
```

How would you spin this up at runtime?

**BTW**, requiring that you use DynamicResource instead is not acceptable.  Does Visual Studio require this?  Yet VS is able to spin up a copy of your WPF framework element and stick it in the designer.

---

Here's a sample application (beta 2, sorry) that demonstrates the issue.

http://cid-f8be9de57b85cc35.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/ResourcesGoKaboom.zip

The app attempts to load a Page with a drawing in its resource dictionary.  I try to load it dynamically using **Application.LoadComponent** and **Activator.CreateInstance** and they both fail.

---

Okay, the example above works without an issue.  The issue was that I was using a StaticResource within an element's attributes that referenced a resource defined within that element.

What was throwing me was that *this works within visual studio.*  So in the designer everything looked okey dokey but IRL it was all pear shaped.  IMHO, this is a bug and I've reported it as such:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=519244

Not sure if its a failure of VS to.... fail, or if the StaticResource extension was working in VS but not IRL.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem -- the Page object instantiates fine using Activator.CreateInstance, and I can use the instantiated Page in a Frame, and the ContentControl and template TextBlock both appear correctly.  Could you provide more details about the inner exception that makes you think this is StaticResource-related?  Can you confirm that you see the failure even with this simplified example?

Comment: btw, its amazing I didn't screw up the xaml when typing it from memory into SO's editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the Page you're trying to load.  Your Page looks like this (omitting a bunch of xmlns etc. plumbing):

```
<AwesomePage Title="AwesomePage" Background="{StaticResource awesomeface}">
    <AwesomePage.Resources>
        <DrawingBrush x:Key="awesomeface" Stretch="Uniform">
            <!-- details snipped -->
        </DrawingBrush>
    </AwesomePage.Resources>
</AwesomePage>
```

This tries to use the awesomeface resource before it is defined.  StaticResource does not allow this kind of forward referencing: therefore the StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue fails and you get the error you have run into.

To fix this, put a Border immediately inside the Page, and move the Background setter from the Page to the Border.  Then put all your content inside the Border.

Comment: Hmmmmm........  It works in VS, however it doesn't work *outside of VS*.  Let me check some more on this...

Comment: Okay, that works.  The thing that was screwing me up was that it WORKED in visual studio, but it does NOT WORK when the application runs.  This, imho, is a bug.